# why can't I change the content of char pointer?

Tags: c

```
void test(char *str2) {
    *str2 = "bbbb";
}

int main(void) {
    char *str1="aaaa";
    test(str1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`str1*` and `str2*` point to the same address why I can not change the value of str1 inside the test function?
thanks all

Comment: Trying to modify string literals will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Using functions that are not declared or defined *before* is not good.

Comment: how do you know it didn't? did you print it out? where is the rest of the code then? seems like you knew the answer before writing the code

Comment: pass by reference instead of passing by value. like @MikeCAT shows below.

Comment: Also see [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with char *s but not char s`[]`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha).

Comment: In any case `*str2 = "bbbb";` does not copy a string. You have to use `strcpy(str2, "bbbb");` (if the destination is legal).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify value of `str1` because `test()` won't know where `str1` is. To have callee modify caller's local variables, pass pointers to what should be modified.

```
void test(char **str2){*str2 = "bbbb";}
int main(void) {char *str1="aaaa";test(&str1);return EXIT_SUCCESS;}
```

Comment: why its pass by value? if i add this prints i get the same address              int main(void) { char *str1="aaaa";printf("%p\n",str1);test(str1);return EXIT_SUCCESS;}void test(char *str2) {printf("%p\n",str2);*str2 = "bbbb";}

Comment: @user1703186 Because what is printed in `test` is the address passed from `main` and then printed in `main`...